# How best to display an eventually periodic sequence in LaTeX

Tags: tables, math-mode, resize, sequence

I want to show that having computed some values, my sequences appear to be eventually periodic. Both sequences are periodic after the first 34 and 48 values respectively and have period 34 and 48.

I was trying to do this by displaying a table for each with, say 4 rows and 34/48 columns, where all but the first row are identical. I thought it would also be nice to have the numbers which have changed from the first row to the second row in bold.

Obviously 34/48 columns is really large so I'm not sure how to fit it in within the line width where it is still readable and looks nice. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to implement this or a better suggestion for a nice way to display the periodic sequence?

Comment: You can use xy-graphics or related, like here: https://www.thno.org/v09/p6856/thnov09p6856g001.jpg . // Perhaps it's good, when you provide some example, like 012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567, which works with characters or symbols, too.

Comment: The sequences are: 
0,1,1,0,2,1,3,0,1,1,3,2,2,3,4,1,5,3,2,2,3,1,1,0,3,1,2,0,1,1,4,4,2, 4,1,1,0,2,1,3,0,1,1,3,2,2,3,4,4,5,7,2,2,3,1,1,0,3,1,2,0,1,1,4,4,3, 4,1,1,0,2,1,3,0,1,1,3,2,2,3,4,4,5,7,2,2,3,1,1,0,3,1,2,0,1,1,4,4,3

and 

0,1,1,1,0,2,2,1,3,4,0,1,1,1,3,2,2,2,3,4,0,1,5,4,3,2,2,2,3,1,0,1,0,4,3,2,2,2,0,1,0,1,0,4,3,2,5, 0,1,0,1,0,2,3,2,3,4,0,1,0,1,3,2,3,2,3,4,0,1,0,4,3,2,3,2,3,1,0,1,0,4,3,2,3,2,0,1,0,1,0,4,3,2,3, 0,1,0,1,0,2,3,2,3,4,0,1,0,1,3,2,3,2,3,4,0,1,0,4,3,2,3,2,3,1,0,1,0,4,3,2,3,2,0,1,0,1,0,4,3,2,3

Comment: Would you be able to explain how I could use xy-graphics? Not exactly sure what I am looking at in the link?

Comment: Sure. Call it dispersion. x=integer, narrow plot, y=lines, or „boxes“ etc. Anything that turns „flat“ text into a 2D pattern. Our eyes compare that easily while reading text, you know … // Narrow can be as small as e.g. 1 mm step size. So you can display sequences of roughly 150 values in one A4 textwidth.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't really thought about visualising the sequences in a plot but I'm definitely going to try it now.

Comment: Fine :) Please post later, e.g. as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you steal a bit of space around commas it fits in a default `article` text width. Use `b` not `bx` bold font, so the alignment is preserved.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\,{\kern-.1pt,\kern-.4pt}
\def\!#1{{\fontseries{b}\selectfont#1}}
\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{flushleft}
\!0\,1\,1\,0\,2\,1\,3\,0\,1\,1\,3\,2\,2\,3\,4\,\!1\,5\,\!3\,2\,2\,3\,1\,1\,0\,3\,1\,2\,0\,1\,1\,4\,4\,\!2\,\\
4\,1\,1\,0\,2\,1\,3\,0\,1\,1\,3\,2\,2\,3\,4\,4\,5\,7\,2\,2\,3\,1\,1\,0\,3\,1\,2\,0\,1\,1\,4\,4\,3\,\\
4\,1\,1\,0\,2\,1\,3\,0\,1\,1\,3\,2\,2\,3\,4\,4\,5\,7\,2\,2\,3\,1\,1\,0\,3\,1\,2\,0\,1\,1\,4\,4\,3
\end{flushleft}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{flushleft}
0\,1\,\!1\,1\,0\,2\,\!2\,\!1\,3\,4\,0\,1\,\!1\,1\,3\,2\,\!2\,2\,3\,4\,0\,1\,\!5\,4\,3\,2\,\!2\,2\,3\,1\,0\,1\,0\,4\,3\,\!2\,2\,2\,0\,1\,0\,1\,0\,4\,3\,2\,\!5\,\\
0\,1\,0\,1\,0\,2\,3\,2\,3\,4\,0\,1\,0\,1\,3\,2\,3\,2\,3\,4\,0\,1\,0\,4\,3\,2\,3\,2\,3\,1\,0\,1\,0\,4\,3\,2\,3\,2\,0\,1\,0\,1\,0\,4\,3\,2\,3\,\\
0\,1\,0\,1\,0\,2\,3\,2\,3\,4\,0\,1\,0\,1\,3\,2\,3\,2\,3\,4\,0\,1\,0\,4\,3\,2\,3\,2\,3\,1\,0\,1\,0\,4\,3\,2\,3\,2\,0\,1\,0\,1\,0\,4\,3\,2\,3
\end{flushleft}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly.

Comment: The redefinitions should go inside `flushright`, not be global

Comment: @egreg naturally yes, or better in a custom `\newenviroment`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way combining the `\rules` approach with `tikz`. This may be helpful when indicating periodic effects, like so:

[image]

New:

- `textcolor` for `\rule`
- embedding the barchart-text in a `tikz-node`
- adding same lines and text to the `tikzpicture` via `\draw`

Uncomment the `help lines` for adjusting the lines drawn.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{calc}% to calculate rule-heights
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{color}

% ~~~ data ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\A[0]{%
 0,1,1,0,2,1,3,0,1,1,3,2,2,3,4,1,5,3,2,2,3,1,1,0,3,1,2,0,1,1,4,4,2, 4,1,1,0,2,1,3,0,1,1,3,2,2,3,4,4,5,7,2,2,3,1,1,0,3,1,2,0,1,1,4,4,3, 4,1,1,0,2,1,3,0,1,1,3,2,2,3,4,4,5,7,2,2,3,1,1,0,3,1,2,0,1,1,4,4,3}
 
\newcommand\B[0]{%
0,1,1,1,0,2,2,1,3,4,0,1,1,1,3,2,2,2,3,4,0,1,5,4,3,2,2,2,3,1,0,1,0,4,3,2,2,2,0,1,0,1,0,4,3,2,5, 0,1,0,1,0,2,3,2,3,4,0,1,0,1,3,2,3,2,3,4,0,1,0,4,3,2,3,2,3,1,0,1,0,4,3,2,3,2,0,1,0,1,0,4,3,2,3, 0,1,0,1,0,2,3,2,3,4,0,1,0,1,3,2,3,2,3,4,0,1,0,4,3,2,3,2,3,1,0,1,0,4,3,2,3,2,0,1,0,1,0,4,3,2,3}
 
 
% ~~~ what the datatool (DTL) shall print ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
\renewcommand{\DTLlistformatsep}{}% no commas printed
\renewcommand{\DTLlistformatlastsep}{}% no spacing between last two items
\renewcommand{\DTLandname}{}% no "and", "&" etc. between last two items
\renewcommand{\DTLlistformatitem}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\rule{2.2pt}{1cm*#1}}}% bars=rule

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%   \draw [help lines] (-3,-3) grid (3,3);
    \node {\DTLformatlist{\A}};
    \draw [dashed,red] (-1,-3) -- (-1,4);% indicator
\end{tikzpicture}
\bigskip
  
\begin{tikzpicture}
%   \draw [help lines] (-3,-3) grid (3,3);
    \node {\DTLformatlist{\B}};
    \draw [dashed,red]  (-1.8 ,-3) -- (-1.8 ,3);% indicator
    \draw [dashed,red]  ( 1.85,-3) -- ( 1.85,3);% indicator
    \draw [{Stealth}-{Stealth},red!70]  (-1.8,2.6) -- node [yshift=1em] {periodic} ( 1.85,2.6);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very beautiful, much better than I had plotted myself. Thank you!

Comment: Fine :) Thank you. // Within your document it may be a good idea to have at least the tabular and the visual perspective: people recognize different things, with varying preferences.

Comment: yes absolutely, I am going to include both. My initial question was mainly asking about the tabular version but after your suggestion and examples, I am definitely including the visualisation of the sequence as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can just input the first two rows and have automatically the changed items emphasized.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% eventually periodic
\NewDocumentCommand{\ep}{O{}mm}
 {% #1 = font size, #2 = first row, #3 = further rows
  \mbox { #1 \max_ep:nn { #2 } { #3 } }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__max_ep_first_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__max_ep_first_out_seq
\seq_new:N \l__max_ep_second_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \max_ep:nn
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__max_ep_first_in_seq { #1 }
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__max_ep_second_seq { #2 }
  \seq_clear:N \l__max_ep_first_out_seq
  \seq_mapthread_function:NNN \l__max_ep_first_in_seq \l__max_ep_second_seq \__max_ep_diff:nn
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  \seq_use:Nn \l__max_ep_first_out_seq { , } , \\
  \seq_use:Nn \l__max_ep_second_seq { , } , \\
  \seq_use:Nn \l__max_ep_second_seq { , } , \\
  \dots
  \end{tabular}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__max_ep_diff:nn
 {
  \str_if_eq:nnTF { #1 } { #2 }
   {% items are equal
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__max_ep_first_out_seq { #1 }
   }
   {% items differ
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__max_ep_first_out_seq
     { \makebox[\fontcharwd\font`0]{\fontseries{b}\selectfont #1} }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{flushleft}
\ep{
  0,1,1,0,2,1,3,0,1,1,3,2,2,3,4,1,5,3,2,2,3,1,1,0,3,1,2,0,1,1,4,4,2
}{
  4,1,1,0,2,1,3,0,1,1,3,2,2,3,4,4,5,7,2,2,3,1,1,0,3,1,2,0,1,1,4,4,3
}
\end{flushleft}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{flushleft}
\ep[\small]{
  0,1,1,1,0,2,2,1,3,4,0,1,1,1,3,2,2,2,3,4,0,1,5,4,3,2,2,2,3,1,0,1,0,4,3,2,2,2,0,1,0,1,0,4,3,2,5
}{
  0,1,0,1,0,2,3,2,3,4,0,1,0,1,3,2,3,2,3,4,0,1,0,4,3,2,3,2,3,1,0,1,0,4,3,2,3,2,0,1,0,1,0,4,3,2,3
}
\end{flushleft}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```

The idea is to populate two sequences with the given arguments. The first one is compared with the second one item by item, adding the item as is if there's no change, with boldface selected otherwise.

Next a tabular is made by using the sequences, with commas reinserted.

An optional argument for a font size selection can be used if the sequence is too long.

The curious

```
\makebox[\fontcharwd\font`0]{\fontseries{b}\selectfont #1}
```

is because bold is not optically scaled in Computer Modern, so I set the different digit in a box as wide as the normal ones.

[image]

In the following version, `*` in the first argument means a blank.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% eventually periodic
\NewDocumentCommand{\ep}{O{}mm}
 {% #1 = font size, #2 = first row, #3 = further rows
  \mbox { #1 \max_ep:nn { #2 } { #3 } }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__max_ep_first_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__max_ep_first_out_seq
\seq_new:N \l__max_ep_second_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \max_ep:nn
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__max_ep_first_in_seq { #1 }
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__max_ep_second_seq { #2 }
  \seq_clear:N \l__max_ep_first_out_seq
  \seq_mapthread_function:NNN \l__max_ep_first_in_seq \l__max_ep_second_seq \__max_ep_diff:nn
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  \seq_use:Nn \l__max_ep_first_out_seq { } \\
  \seq_use:Nn \l__max_ep_second_seq { , } , \\
  \seq_use:Nn \l__max_ep_second_seq { , } , \\
  \dots
  \end{tabular}
 }



\cs_new_protected:Nn \__max_ep_diff:nn
 {
  \str_if_eq:nnTF { #1 } { * }
   {% blank
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__max_ep_first_out_seq { \mbox{\phantom{0,}} }
   }
   {% non blank
    \str_if_eq:nnTF { #1 } { #2 }
     {% items are equal
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l__max_ep_first_out_seq { #1, }
     }
     {% items differ
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l__max_ep_first_out_seq
       { \makebox[\fontcharwd\font`0]{\fontseries{b}\selectfont #1}, }
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{flushleft}
\ep{
  0,1,1,0,2,1,3,0,1,1,3,2,2,3,4,1,5,3,2,2,3,1,1,0,3,1,2,0,1,1,4,4,2
}{
  4,1,1,0,2,1,3,0,1,1,3,2,2,3,4,4,5,7,2,2,3,1,1,0,3,1,2,0,1,1,4,4,3
}
\end{flushleft}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{flushleft}
\ep[\small]{
  0,1,1,1,0,2,2,1,3,4,0,1,1,1,3,2,2,2,3,4,0,1,5,4,3,2,2,2,3,1,0,1,0,4,3,2,2,2,0,1,0,1,0,4,3,2,5
}{
  0,1,0,1,0,2,3,2,3,4,0,1,0,1,3,2,3,2,3,4,0,1,0,4,3,2,3,2,3,1,0,1,0,4,3,2,3,2,0,1,0,1,0,4,3,2,3
}
\end{flushleft}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{flushleft}
\ep{
  *,1,2,3,4,5,6
}{
  0,0,2,3,4,5,6
}
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! A quick question. I now have a different sequence in which the preperiod (number of values until period begins) is one less than the period. Obviously this messes up the alignments, is there a way to start the top row shifted one (number sized) space in from the left and keep the remaining rows the same?

Comment: @Max I added a version that allows specifying blanks in the first argumen.

Comment: Perfect thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's a visual way to do it.

Main steps:

- `\A` and `\B` provide the data
- package `datatool (\DTL...)` gives access to the individual data
- the `\renewcommand`s define, how the data are printed
- a simple `\rule{}{}` creates a barchart-like diagram
- change width and height there
- introduce textcolor for the rules, if you like

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{calc}% to calculate rule-heights
\usepackage{datatool}

% ~~~ data ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\A[0]{%
 0,1,1,0,2,1,3,0,1,1,3,2,2,3,4,1,5,3,2,2,3,1,1,0,3,1,2,0,1,1,4,4,2, 4,1,1,0,2,1,3,0,1,1,3,2,2,3,4,4,5,7,2,2,3,1,1,0,3,1,2,0,1,1,4,4,3, 4,1,1,0,2,1,3,0,1,1,3,2,2,3,4,4,5,7,2,2,3,1,1,0,3,1,2,0,1,1,4,4,3}
 
\newcommand\B[0]{%
0,1,1,1,0,2,2,1,3,4,0,1,1,1,3,2,2,2,3,4,0,1,5,4,3,2,2,2,3,1,0,1,0,4,3,2,2,2,0,1,0,1,0,4,3,2,5, 0,1,0,1,0,2,3,2,3,4,0,1,0,1,3,2,3,2,3,4,0,1,0,4,3,2,3,2,3,1,0,1,0,4,3,2,3,2,0,1,0,1,0,4,3,2,3, 0,1,0,1,0,2,3,2,3,4,0,1,0,1,3,2,3,2,3,4,0,1,0,4,3,2,3,2,3,1,0,1,0,4,3,2,3,2,0,1,0,1,0,4,3,2,3}
 
 
% ~~~ what the datatool (DTL) shall print ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
\renewcommand{\DTLlistformatsep}{}% no commas printed
\renewcommand{\DTLlistformatlastsep}{}% no spacing between last two items
\renewcommand{\DTLandname}{}% no "and", "&" etc. between last two items
\renewcommand{\DTLlistformatitem}[1]{\rule{2.2pt}{1cm*#1}}% bars=rule

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
    Sequence A, with \DTLnumitemsinlist{\A}{\listnum}\listnum \ data:
    
    \fbox{\DTLformatlist{\A}}
    \bigskip    
    
    Sequence B, with \DTLnumitemsinlist{\B}{\listnum}\listnum \ data:

    \fbox{\DTLformatlist{\B}}
    \bigskip
    
    Both sequences are periodic after about $30$ \% of data, measured from the start.

\end{document}
```